# Dynamic table from Firebase using JavaScript for website

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a table using Google Firebase in JavaScript, but its not showing the table.

Here is my code:

```
 <a href="#usertable" onclick="openLink(event,'usertable');tab1();" class="tablink w3-padding w3-hover-white" style="margin-top: 2px;font-size: 15px;">User Table</a>  <!--function called on click on tab link-->


                <table  id="userTableInside" class="w3-table w3-centered w3-striped w3-card-2">
                    <tr  style="background: #cccccc;">
                      <th>Institute Name</th>
                      <th>Role id</th>
                      <th>Institute id</th>
                      <th>Strikes</th>
                      <th>Status</th>

                      <!--<th>Perfomance Rating</th>-->
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="mytr">

                    </tr>

                </table>
```

Added the src script tag above

```
<script>

//initialized firebase also
function tab1() {
    var table= document.getElementById("userTableInside");
    var i = 1;
    var institudeId = sessionStorage.getItem("InstituteId");
    var roleId = sessionStorage.getItem("RoleId");
    var ref_1 = firebase.database.ref(institudeId + "/Admin/Usertable/");
    ref_1.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

            var row= table.insertRows(i);
            var x= row.insertCell(0);
            var x1= row.insertCell(1);
            var x2= row.insertCell(2);
            x.innerHTML = childData.status;
            x1.innerHTML = childData.totalTimeUsed;
            x2.innerHTML = childData.report;
            i++;
            // ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `var childData = childSnapshot.val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems fine to me, except the `snapshot.forEach`. Before using the values in the `snapshot`, First extract the values from the snapshot using `snapshot.val()`.

Use `snapshot.val().forEach`. Hope this will solve your problem.

**Note:**
The `listener` receives a snapshot that contains the data at the specified location in the **database** at the time of the event. You can `retrieve` the data in the snapshot with the **val()** method.

I didn't check the table insertion logic as i found that snapshot is used directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the data to the table

$("#userTableInside > tbody").append("" + data for col 1 + "" + data for col 2 + "" + data for col 3 + "");

use the proper variable instead of "data for col 1" etc.
make sure you end with a  to indicate the end of the table row.

Do this for each time you loop thru your "children" - basically just replace your code in the same place